# How can I subtract values within a single column of SQLite table?

Tags: sqlite

My original table in sqlite is as follows:

```
--------------------
names_ID  | values
--------------------
frank     | 31
chris     | 50
chris     | 40
tim       | 65
tim       | 85
```

Then I apply the following query:

```
SELECT names_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(values, ',') FROM table GROUP BY names_ID
```

From the above query I get the following table:

```
--------------------
names_ID  | values
--------------------
frank     | 31
chris     | 50,40
tim       | 65,85
```

For rows where there are two values separated by a comma, I would like to get the percentage of these two values (for example, for the 'tim' row, the percentage would be 65/85 *100 = 76.5).

I would like my expected result to be:

```
--------------------
names_ID  | percent
--------------------
chris     | 80
tim       | 76.5
```

I have been unable to come up with an attempt that comes anywhere close to my desired output. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why is the order of data different for chris and tim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *don't* need to go through CSV to answer your question I think.  If each name really only has two values (at most) associated with it, then a simple `GROUP BY` aggregation should work:

```
SELECT
    names_ID,
    CAST(MIN(values) AS float) / CAST(MAX(values) AS float) * 100 AS percent
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY names_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Note: I don't like the idea of grouping by `names_ID`, because first names may not be unique across even a small group of people.  Rather, `names_ID` should probably be an auto increment column, and you should create a new column called `names` which contains the actual name text.

Comment: I used the following to aggregate the values for names that were repeated in the rows of the table:`SELECT names_ID,
GROUP_CONCAT(values, ',') FROM table
GROUP BY names_ID`. The result was the table shown above. Do you have any suggestion as per your disclaimer to do the percent calculation when the values are in separate rows? thanks.

Comment: @unknown121 Do _not_ dump your code here.  Just advise me as to whether your query is working.

Comment: The original table used to create the subsequent table with separated commas are now shown by an edit to my orginal post.

Comment: Tim, this did not produce the output. I get the percent as zero for both 'chris and 'tim'.

Comment: @unknown121 Please try my updated query.  Cast both numerator and denominator to `float` before dividing.